# Select rows with multiple distinct column value combinations

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, postgresql-9.1

I have a table with 3 columns: `id`, `val1` and `val2`.

For each distinct value of val2 I want to select all rows for which *multiple* distinct values of val1 exist.

Example:

```
| id | val1 | val2 |
|------------------|
| 1  | A1   |  a2  |
| 2  | A1   |  a2  |
| 3  | A1   |  b2  |
| 4  | B1   |  b2  |
| 5  | A1   |  c2  |
| 6  | A1   |  c2  |
| 7  | A1   |  c2  |
| 8  | A1   |  d2  |
| 9  | C1   |  d2  |
| 10 | A1   |  d2  |
```

Desired result:

```
| id | val1 | val2 |
|------------------|
| 3  | A1   |  b2  |
| 4  | B1   |  b2  |
| 8  | A1   |  d2  |
| 9  | C1   |  d2  |
| 10 | A1   |  d2  |
```

I did not manage to come up with any query which allows me to do this, maybe someone else has an idea on how to solve this.

Comment: What DB system? MSSQL 2005/08/12, MySQL...

Comment: Rows 8 and 10 are identical except for the ID number. I don't understand why you would include 8 and 10, but exclude 1 and 2, which are also identical except for the id number.

Comment: @Catcall: only 1 distinct value for val1 exists for val2=a2 (row 1-2), but more than 1 distinct values for val1 exist for val2=d2 (row 8-10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using aggregate window functions, you could also do it like this:

```
SELECT
  id,
  val1,
  val2
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    MIN(val1) OVER (PARTITION BY val2) AS minval1,
    MAX(val1) OVER (PARTITION BY val2) AS maxval1
  FROM atable
) s
WHERE minval1 <> maxval1
```

Comment: very nice, your query is nearly twice as fast for me. and it is more readable.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a `having` clause to search for `val2` with more than one distinct value of `val1`.  For example:

```
select  yt.*
from    YourTable yt
join    (
        select  val2
        from    YourTable
        group by
                val2
        having  count(distinct val1) > 1
        ) as filter
on      yt.val2 = filter.val2
```

Comment: @aF: It does match the example results, see Paddy's [SQLFIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0dc5e/1)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE_2 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   (SELECT val2, 
                              val1, 
                              Count(*) AS Number 
                       FROM   TABLE_2 
                       GROUP  BY val2, 
                                 val1 
                       HAVING Count(*) = 1) a 
               WHERE  TABLE_2.val2 = a.val2) 
ORDER  BY ID
```

Comment: @Romil: yes it works now, since both your and Andomars queries are correct i will check which yields better performance with larger table (my table is not that large however)

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * from tbl where val2 in (SELECT  val2 FROM `tbl`  group by val2 having  
 count(distinct(val1)) > 1)
```